# SOAP method call extremely slow

Tags: php, performance, soap

I am working on a project which relies heavily on SOAP calls. The problem is that load times a re extremely long.

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://link.to.wsdl");
$client = $client->GetDestination(array(
"parameter1" => $param1,
"parameter2" => $param2
));
```

Now I did some timing and the first part of the code(initiating an object $client) takes about 2 seconds, very acceptable. But when calling getDestination it adds about 10 seconds loading time. This is with every get or set method that I call.

This code is running on php 5. The methods are written in .net 4.x

Does anyone know why this is and how it can be solved?

EDIT: ping statistics
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.086/2.320/3.624/1.157 ms

Comment: If you ping the destination, how long does it take to respond?

Comment: 10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.086/2.320/3.624/1.157 ms

Comment: In case it helps someone at some point, my problem turned out to be the DNS resolution time. For whatever reason, each call was looking up the domain (which was on the same server). I added it to the hosts file and each call changed from 5 seconds to 0 seconds :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you should enable WSDL caching using the [`soap.wsdl_cache_enabled`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soap.configuration.php#ini.soap.wsdl-cache-enabled) ini value or using the `$options` param of the [`SoapClient`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) constructor. This would prevent PHP from downloading the wsdl again and again and will speedup the constructor (2 seconds it also very long)

To speedup the method calls itself, I need more information. Are you able to use [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to introspect the network communication between your app and the soap server?

Comment: The wsdl cache is already enabled. I might be able to use wireshark, but I am not sure what I should be looking for and where I should run it from?

Comment: Are you sure wsdl caching works? Have a look at the cache dir. Do you see wsdls? Are those wsdl's importing external refereneces which must be downloaded? Wireshark: Check how long it takes until the response is delivered. If this takes really 10 sec, then there is a performance issue with the server

Comment: Well, it appears that the wsdl caching didn't work. But that problem is fixed now, it cut off like 2 seconds of the time. Now it takes approximately 10 seconds to load a page.


I used Wireshark to check for xml and it really takes that long to respond. It could be the server, I am not sure.

Comment: Looks like it is the server. Do you have an url for me? If you're using mostly read operations, you could use a HTTP proxy between you and the server

Comment: also adding user_agent option to soapClient constructor helps with performance

'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0',

Comment: Thank you - for me the cache was enabled but the cache directory was invalid. Fixing this took the time down from 20 seconds to 0 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue connecting to a SOAP service on the same machine as my code. It was resolved by using `http://127.0.0.1/` instead of `http://localhost/` as the url.

Comment: This often occurs because the local machine doesn't have a DNS entry for `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

hello if you are on plesk check this doc
https://docs.plesk.com/fr-FR/obsidian/administrator-guide/g%C3%A9rer-des-sites-web/sites-web-et-domaines/param%C3%A8tres-d%E2%80%99h%C3%A9bergement/param%C3%A8tres-de-script-web/param%C3%A8tres-php.70742/

https://docs.plesk.com/fr-FR/obsidian/administrator-guide/h%C3%A9bergement-web/gestion-de-php/types-de-gestionnaires-php.75145/

for me I must set "exec php as FPM by apache " in php settings of my site